# Is it possible to see live properties for ContextMenu in VS2015 Live Visual Tree?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, debugging

Visual studio 2015 presented "Live Visual Tree" debug tool. It's pretty convinient and I've already used it with ordinary elements, but now I want to use it with `ContextMenu`.

I know that `ContextMenu` exists in separate visual tree and I wonder is it possible somehow to use new VS2015 debug features to see live properties for ContextMenu.

Comment: Snoop lets you do this by holding down a key on the keyboard to focus on hover.  Would be nice if they had implemented it in that way.

Comment: The same question for `flyouts` -- as soon as focus lost they disappeared ((( so, no way to debug them

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is just not capable of doing this for popups. Use Snoop instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You could try the WPF Inspector for analyzing wpf applications.
It attaches to running wpf programs and allow you to get detailed Information about controls on it. Simply hover over the control you want to gather information from while pressing Ctrl.

The Wpf Inspector also provides you with an Logical and Visual Tree.

For more information see here: https://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/